# Display certain number of lines from text file

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to display the first 10 lines of text in a file. However it just display the whole file instead of limiting it to 10 lines.

```
int count = 0;

string input = "";

fstream file;

file.open("Test.txt", ios::in);

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) {

    getline(file, input);

    cout << input; 
}
```

Comment: what is the content of your file?

Comment: If I were you, i would put a double endl after "input", to see exactly what the programs sees as a line

Comment: This prints 11 lines because of <=, but not the whole file over here.

Comment: Did you run in windows or Linux? It can happen that your C++ runtime has different definition of EOL (`\r\n` for Windows, `\n` for Linux) with what you expect.

Comment: It prints 11 lines and does not handle the case when file.open fails.

Comment: And also does not handle if the file is less than 11 lines.

Comment: In order to read a file more portable, open the file in binary mode (std::ios::binary)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not your homework helper dude.  This is a site for professional quality questions, not for debugging or homework help.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone, while there are professional quality questions that is not the primary reason for this site. It is a valuable resource for programmers to come together and help and receive help for problems. I didn't come here to have someone do my homework as shown I have done work myself I just ran into an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work, but what's causing this might be:

Case1: dont tell me your input file has no newline char and got wrapped. cus thats going to be stupid -.-

Case2: try to add `cout << input << endl;` and see if its printing the whole file or just print the file line by line

also its printing 11 lines so you might want to change `<=` to `<`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to bisthebis's suggestion (I'd change it to print '----'), check the line endings for your file. Mac uses '\r', Unix/Linux use '\n' and Windows uses '\r\n'. If you are on Windows, you can get notepad++ to show hidden characters.

Also, as per c++ spec (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/), getline only considers '\n' as new line separator.

Comment: But as in this case if the file is opened in a text mode, then the '\r\n' will be translated to '\n' in windows. I'm not sure about mac though.

Comment: Is the behavior different or same for cin>> and getline?

Comment: I meant when opening a file using a file stream in a text mode, cin is the standard input stream(keyboard) and *getline* and extraction *operator>>* are available for both streams

Comment: Sorry, I meant the >> operator and getline function.

Comment: As far as i could remember, yes.